# Number of recent items not working

Tags: macos

Applications like for example `TextEdit` show multiple entries in the `Open Recent` list despite that the number of recent items is set to `none` in the system preferences.

Is there another way to adjust the number of recent items? Or to automatically clear the lists of all applications on logout?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of `Recent Items` in TextEdit or other applications is independent from the general settings in the `System Preferences`.
The amount of entries and the entries itself are stored in *.LSSharedFileList.plist files.

Example:

**PlistEdit Pro method**
To change the number for TextEdit clear the menu in TextEdit, quit TextEdit, open com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList.plist in ~/Library/Preferences/ with an appropriate application (e.g. [PlistEdit Pro (free 14-day trial)](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/plisteditpro/)) and enter 0 as MaxAmount.

[image: com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList.plist]

You may have to create (if the file doesn't exist) and modify com.apple.TextEdit.plist afterwards:

```
touch ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist
```

to create the file `com.apple.TextEdit.plist`

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSRecentDocumentsLimit 0
```

to change the preferences.

**plutil and nano method**

Quit TextEdit and open Terminal.app and enter:

```
touch ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist
```

to create the file `com.apple.TextEdit.plist` if it doesn't exist

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSRecentDocumentsLimit 0
```

to change the preferences

```
plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList.plist
```

to convert the file to XML.

Open the file with nano

```
nano ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList.plist
```

and edit the value of `MaxAmount`, write out your edit to file with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and exit nano  <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>
and finally

```
plutil -convert binary1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList.plist
```

to convert it back to the original binary format.

**defaults method** works with 10.7, 10.8 and obviously 10.9:

```
defaults delete com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList RecentDocuments
touch ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.plist (if the file doesn't exist)
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSRecentDocumentsLimit 0
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList RecentDocuments -dict-add MaxAmount 0
killall Dock
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially your third solution works for me.

Comment: @samcarter In Mavericks the last version didn't work for me at all. The file reverted to it's defaults (MaxAmount 10) most of the time. Maybe too much testing ;-)

Comment: strange, I experienced this the other way round. First I tried to edit the .plist with XCode (similar to your first solution) but this did not work. Every time I opened TextEdit the MaxAmount was set back to 10. But your command line approach worked on the first try.

Comment: @samcarter i didn't have a com.apple.TextEdit.plist file in my prefs folder at the beginning. Maybe that's the reason for the strange behavior